# GCM returns Unauthorized

Tags: google-api-php-client

Im using an android to develop an application and I would like to add push notification mechanism, all looks good until I created the PHP server... Im getting

> Unauthorized
>
> Error 401

all the time, what I have done is to whitelist my server @ **Notifications Endpoints**, I dont use OAuth, needs something else ?

for APIkey using the one for the specific app :
[image: descr]

my php call header is like

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . "xxxxz0DIAOSAW90YmI",
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

whats is wrong!?

I know there is many issues like this, is not double-post, google change the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems I have to create also at **Registered apps** section an entry for my server as described at http://goo.gl/vN3SYi

now working!

Comment: You could have written directly in the answer that: one needs to create a new API KEY and leave the IPS field blank. I guess it would be faster for people looking just for this bit.